# MAX() in WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

The following sql, with the MAX aggregrate function in the WHERE clause, does not work:

```
  SELECT 
   ID,
   title, 
   relevance

  FROM
   myTable

  WHERE
   (relevance <= MAX(relevance)/2)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  myTable is a temporary table, so cannot be referenced again using a sub-query. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET @MaxRel=(SELECT MAX(relevance)/2 FROM myTable);
SELECT ID,title,relevance FROM myTable WHERE (relevance <= @MaxRel);
```

May this help

Answer (score 3):

try using [sub query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparisons-using-subqueries.html)

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   title, 
   relevance
  FROM
   myTable
  WHERE
   (relevance <= (SELECT MAX(relevance)/2 FROM myTable))
```

another way using having like

```
SELECT 
       ID,
       title, 
       relevance
      FROM
       myTable
      GROUP BY ID
      HAVING
       (relevance <= MAX(relevance)/2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately myTable is a temporary table, so can only be referred to once in the same query

Comment: the HAVING clause is a where on an aggregate, that would be the correct answer

Comment: Use Common Table Expressions instead of a Temporary Table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    title, 
    relevance
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    (relevance <= (SELECT MAX(relevance) FROM myTable) /2)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  Unfortunately myTable is a temporary table, so cannot be referenced 2x in the same query

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this.  (Untested, so please let me know if this doesn't work as expected.)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
       ID,
       title, 
       relevance,
       IF( relevance > @max, @max := relevance, @max := @max ) AS max_relevance  
    FROM
        mytable,
        (SELECT @max:=0) m
) Q
WHERE relevance <= max_relevance / 2
;
```

[Common MySQL Queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1225) for some good code examples.  Look for *Within-group quotas (Top N per group)* for an example of how to use variables in a query as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

the method to use a variable which is mentioned by naresh is a good way to query the database,
as it creates an ease in understanding the queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    title, 
    relevance
FROM
    myTable inner join (SELECT MAX(relevance) as maxRel FROM myTable) A
WHERE
    (relevance <= (A.maxRel / 2))
```

Should still give you back the same number of rows as before, as "A" has only one row.